# Utility Class for CRUD Operations in a Flask App

Tags: python, beginner, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm new to Flask and Python and am trying to sort out the most pythonic way to modularize my utilities.  I have `models.py` which have my sqlalchemy models and `views.py` which handles the routes, etc... My `util.py` basically handles the queries and data manipulation between the two but I want to know if I'm doing it right. I originally had a bunch of loose functions but I recently began compounding them into classes.

To explain more clearly the purpose of this utility is to retrieve records from the DB and serve the Views with the processed data. In response to some of the answers and comments I'd like to point out that although I'm referencing a Document and Business both of these are part of the same One-To-Many relationship and belong to the Business. (IE: In my app, the Business is referenced as a "Business Record" and therefore the `RecordManager()` class manipulates both Business Information (contained in the Business Table) and Business Documents (contained in the Documents Table). Additionally, the Business is part of a Many-To-Many relationship with the Center.

The following snippet is from my `util.py`:

```
class RecordManager(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__center = Center.query.get(session['center'])
        self.__business = None
        self.__record = None

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self.__record.id

    def all(self, archived=0):
        return self.__center.businesses.filter_by(archived=archived).all()

    def get(self, biz, doc=None, obj=None):
        self.__business = self.__center.businesses.filter_by(bizId=biz).first_or_404()
        if not doc == None:
            return self.__business.info.documents.filter_by(id=doc).first_or_404()
        if obj: return self.__business
        return self.__business.info

    def list(self):
        documents = self.__business.info.documents.with_entities(Document.typId).all()
        if not documents:
            documents = [[-1,-1]]
        return zip(*documents)[0]

    def store(self, form):
        if hasattr(form, 'bizId'):
            if form.id.data == 'new':
                self.__record = Document(typId=form.type.data, bizId=form.bizId.data,
                                         expiry=form.expiry.data)
                db.session.add(self.__record)
            else:
                self.__record = self.get(form.bizId.data, form.id.data)
                self.__record.expiry = form.expiry.data
        else:
            if form.id.data == 'new':
                assoc = CenterBusiness()
                assoc.info = Business(typId=form.type.data, name=form.name.data,
                                      contact=form.contact.data, phone=form.phone.data)
                self.__center.businesses.append(assoc)
                db.session.add(self.__center)
                self.__record = assoc.info
            else:
                self.__record = self.get(form.id.data)
                self.__record.name = form.name.data
                self.__record.typId = form.type.data
                self.__record.contact = form.contact.data
                self.__record.phone = form.phone.data
        db.session.commit()
        return self.__record.id

    def archive(self, biz):
        self.__record = self.get(biz, obj=True)
        self.__record.archived = 1
        db.session.commit()
        return self.__record.bizId

    def delete(self, biz, doc=None):
        if not doc == None:
            self.__record = self.get(biz, doc)
            db.session.delete(self.__record)
            db.session.commit()
            return doc
        self.__record = self.get(biz)
        return biz
```

The following is from my `views.py` and both routes reference and use the `RecordManager()`.

```
@app.route('/manager', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
@center_required
def biz_manage():
    records = RecordManager()
    data = get_user_data()
    form = BusinessForm()
    form.type.choices = [(c.id, c.name) for c in BizType.query.order_by('id')]
    if form.validate_on_submit() and records.store(form):
        if form.id.data == 'new':
            return redirect(url_for('doc_manage', record=records.id))
        flash('Record has been successfully updated.', 'info')
        return redirect(url_for('biz_manage'))
    data['biz_list'] = records.all()
    return render_template('manager.html', data=data, form=form)

@app.route('/manager/record/<record>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
@center_required
def doc_manage(record):
    records = RecordManager()
    data = get_user_data()
    form = DocumentForm()
    form.type.choices = [(c.id, c.name) for c in DocType.query.order_by('id')]
    if form.validate_on_submit() and records.store(form):
        flash('Document has been successfully updated.', 'info')
        return redirect(url_for('doc_manage', record=record))
    data['record'] = records.get(record)
    data['doc_list'] = records.list()
    data['expire'] = doc_expire(data['record'].documents, 30, 1)
    return render_template('record.html', data=data, form=form)
```

Lastly, this snippet is from my `models.py` and represents the SQLAlchemy models.

```
class Center(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(MEDIUMINT(8, unsigned=True), primary_key=True,
                   autoincrement=False)
    phone = db.Column(VARCHAR(10), nullable=False)
    location = db.Column(VARCHAR(255), nullable=False)
    businesses = db.relationship('CenterBusiness', lazy='dynamic')
    employees = db.relationship('CenterEmployee', lazy='dynamic')

class Business(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(MEDIUMINT(8, unsigned=True), primary_key=True,
                   autoincrement=True)
    typId = db.Column(TINYINT(2, unsigned=True),
                      db.ForeignKey('biz_type.id',
                                    onupdate='RESTRICT',
                                    ondelete='RESTRICT'),
                      nullable=False)
    type = db.relationship('BizType', backref='businesses',
                           lazy='subquery')
    name = db.Column(VARCHAR(255), nullable=False)
    contact = db.Column(VARCHAR(255), nullable=False)
    phone = db.Column(VARCHAR(10), nullable=False)
    documents = db.relationship('Document', backref='business',
                                lazy='dynamic')

class CenterBusiness(db.Model):
    cenId = db.Column(MEDIUMINT(8, unsigned=True),
                      db.ForeignKey('center.id',
                                    onupdate='RESTRICT',
                                    ondelete='RESTRICT'),
                      primary_key=True)
    bizId = db.Column(MEDIUMINT(8, unsigned=True),
                      db.ForeignKey('business.id',
                                    onupdate='RESTRICT',
                                    ondelete='RESTRICT'),
                      primary_key=True)
    info = db.relationship('Business', backref='centers',
                           lazy='joined')
    archived = db.Column(TINYINT(1, unsigned=True), nullable=False,
                         server_default='0')

class Document(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(MEDIUMINT(8, unsigned=True), primary_key=True,
                   autoincrement=True)
    typId = db.Column(TINYINT(2, unsigned=True),
                      db.ForeignKey('doc_type.id',
                                    onupdate='RESTRICT',
                                    ondelete='RESTRICT'),
                      nullable=False)
    type = db.relationship('DocType', backref='documents',
                           lazy='subquery')
    bizId = db.Column(MEDIUMINT(8, unsigned=True),
                      db.ForeignKey('business.id',
                                    onupdate='RESTRICT',
                                    ondelete='RESTRICT'),
                      nullable=False)
    store = db.Column(VARCHAR(255), nullable=True)
    expiry = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### OOP

It seems you're accustomed to organizing your code into functions,
and you're new to organizing into classes.

When creating a class, the most important question to ask is what *Abstract Data Type* (ADT) are you trying to represent. Loosely defined, an abstract data type is a collection of data and functions that work with that data.
Here are some key points to guide you:

- An ADT should have one very clear purpose.

  - See also: *Single Responsibility Principle*
- The data of an ADT should not be accessed directly from the outside. Access an ADT only through its methods.

  - See also: *encapsulation, information hiding*
  - Example: imagine a `Font` instance. The size of a font might be stored in pixels or in points. An implementation will probably use either of the two, but not both. If you ever have to do `font.sizeInPixels = 12`, then you know too much about the implementation. The authors cannot refactor the class to use `sizeInPoints` anymore, without breaking all the code that accesses the internal data directly. If you enforce using only use methods, for example `font.setSizeInPixels(12)`, the internal representation is hidden, and the author is free to change from pixels to points without affecting users.
- The method names of an ADT should use wording in the problem domain.

  - Example: imagine an ADT in charge of an exchange rates table, that stores the rates table in a CSV file. If the method to load the table is called `loadRatesFile`, the term "File" is bad in two ways: it reveals an implementation detail, and it's not in the language of the problem domain. Users of the ADT may find it confusing why it's talking about a "File", when they don't care where the table is coming from. Indeed it could come from anywhere. The author may want to replace the implementation to load the table from a database or a web service. `loadRatesTable` will be a better name in the problem domain, and the implementation will be free to change, without rendering the method name meaningless.

I recommend reading Chapter 6 in Code Complete, it should give you excellent ideas about designing classes well.

In your program, the main class appears to be `RecordManager`.
In terms of the above key points, this class is doing fine,
but only on the surface.
It looks like its purpose is CRUD operations,
but the problem is that it works with `Business` and `Document` objects.
It seems that these concerns should be separated,
perhaps into `BusinessManager` and `DocumentManager` classes.

Speaking of "Business"... `Business`, `Center`, `CenterBusiness` seem wishy-washy, meaningless names.
The purpose of these classes is unclear, I suggest to rethink, keeping in mind the key points I listed above.

Looking at the implementation of the methods of `RecordManager`,
this class knows too much internal details about `Business` and the other classes. For example:

> ```
> def get(self, biz, doc=None, obj=None):
>     self.__business = self.__center.businesses.filter_by(bizId=biz).first_or_404()
>     # ...
> ```

Chained calls like `self.__center.businesses.filter_by` are a sign of too tight coupling. This class knows that `Center` has a field called `businesses`. This detail should be hidden in `Center`, and the filter should only be accessible through a method of `Center`, something like:

```
    self.__business = self.__center.first_business(biz)
```

See also: the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)

#### Style

Python has an official style guide called [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).
It's a very interesting read.
Some of the most notable violations in the posted code:

- Use single `_` prefix for private variables instead of double `__`
- Instead of `not doc == None`, should be `is not None`

  - Likewise, instead of `doc == None`, should be `doc is None`
- Instead of `if obj: return self.__business`, break the line after the `:`

Comment: With regards to the chained methods, these are directly SQLAlchemy methods and would not be easily modified. Additionally, I updated my question to include an explanation of why I'm using `RecordManager()` for both Document and Business. Lastly, the names of the classes in models.py all represent actual SQLAlchemy Tables and are used in the DB directly. I appreciate the feedback overall but hope that this reworked question now alleviates some of the OOP concern.

Comment: It's not clear what is a Business and a Center. Being SQLAlchemy tables is not their purpose, but an implementation detail. Can't you add custom methods in SQLAlchemy? My suggestion about `self.__center.first_business` was not about renaming, but about encapsulating a long chained call.

Comment: Ah okay I had done that with permissions on the users table. Makes sense I'll refactor and also on the Business and Center I hear you it could probably be more appropriately BusinessInfo and CenterInfo. However, due to the relationships I would think center.businesses encapsulates more than just the info stored in the table. Rather the object has access to all assets of the Center and/or Business as a whole?